# Is it possible in ffmpeg to seek to position of the file that is received through stdin

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, stdin

Is it possible to -ss in ffmpeg to the file, that is being received via pipe? So that I start reading it from a given timecode?
I am not encoding the file.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried it already?

Comment: yeah, it always starts from 0

Comment: Maybe you can add the commands you're using and provide a sample file for others to try. I don't know if it's actually possible, but I fear it's not.

Answer (score 0):

So it is definitely impossible.

here is what I was trying to achieve:

```
<wget command here> - | ffmpeg -ss 00:00:03 -t 00:00:10 -i - -y -g 1 -vcodec copy -acodec copy <name of the file>
```

Bad news: the file WILL be downloaded from 00:00:00

Good news: downloading WILL stop at 00:00:10

I guess something close to the desired goal of having a 7-second long clip that starts at 03 initial seconds is achievable through librtmp / streaming and then seeking to the desired timecode, but that sounds like an overkill for what I am doing.